# What is the safest way to root a 5.1.1 so I can use the SD drive?

Tags: sd-card

There is no more "Move to SD" option in Apps Info like there was in 4.4 so now I am grasping at alternatives as my new Android is getting filled up while I have a fully empty 32GB SD drive just sitting there mounted and unused.

Q:  What is the safest way to move these apps out to the drive?

Comment: Without rooting, as you have probably figured out, there is no stock way to move the apps.  However, you might want to consider using EF File Explorer to move data out to the card - live videos and such.  If you use Google Drive, it is pretty easy to get videos from there out to the card instead of having it take up primary memory.

Answer (score 0):

Download the universal android root apk it is not available on google play store so you have to download it on your own after downloading it you are ready to go to root your device